# multiple Angular2 projects with only 1 node module

Tags: angular, npm, node-modules

How can I use one node module in all my angular projects. It's taking too much disk space to copy node modules in each project

Comment: You can put node_modules in a common parent directory, it should work as node resolution looks up folders until it finds a node_modules folder.That being said, there have been issues with @angular-cli which was resolved later, take a look at the discussion [here](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/3864)

Comment: I dont want to put node module in Angular 2 project ,it should be outside & all my Angular 2 demo will access it. I want to do it bcoz node module is heavy file & takes lots of space only one node module & shared by all angular 2 projects . I tried lot but only done without running npm start or ng serve

Answer (score 0):

Basically you want to deploy your component to NPM as a library component, and then you will be able to reference it from your other applications in the same way you do for any other component.

You need to publish the module to npm with the `npm publish` command, and before you can do that you are going to need to create an account in npm. Note that if you wish your component to remain private, you will need to create a paid for account, otherwise the component will be publicly visible to everyone.

To create an account:
Visit https://www.npmjs.com/  and click on the sign up link

Comment: I dont want to put node module in Angular 2 project ,it should be outside & all my Angular 2 demo will access it. I want to do it bcoz node module is heavy file & takes lots of space only one node module & shared by all angular 2 projects . I tried lot but only done without running npm start or ng serve